# Facebook Connect Login redirecting in Chrome and Safari

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, facebook

I am having a problem with Facebook Connect that I can't seem to get my head around. A user clicks on the fb-login button, the pop up appears and they authenticate, the pop up closes and the on-login function is called. This happens in IE and Firefox as is expected. However in Chrome and Safari, the pop up redirects to the canvas url and doesn't close. Also the on-login function isn't called. I have googled and it seems to be something to do with the xd-receiver.htm file, however it seems weird that it is working in IE and Firefox but not Chrome or Safari. Thanks

The facebook javascript

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xd_receiver.htm");</script>
```

And the button

```
<fb:login-button v="2" size="large" onlogin='window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/development/redirect.php?size=large";'>Connect</fb:login-button>
```

Obviously with Appid and domain hidden. Any ideas?

EDIT: After a bit more playing around it turned out that I didn't have my base domain set in Facebook settings. Why it works in some browsers and not others beats me, however it works now. Thanks NSD for your suggestion.

Comment: Enable the Develop menu in Safari and check the console for errors.

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but the last time I saw something like this it ended up being that Chrome was enforcing a security standard that FF and IE were ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the old js sdk has been depreciated https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/  You may need to migrate to OAuth2 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/