# XD Proxy Error on post on wall

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

i have created an facebook application and i request post on wall permission from the user to post stories, all users can post on wall and can easily use the application expect one user get popup with XD Proxy on title. 
the user tested the application with chrome, ff, ie and safari in Windows7.
i am using GraphAPI AS3.

Comment: This might help you http://paragy.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/facebook-login-hangs-blank-page-shown-xd-proxy-issue/

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue in IE9, and it seemed to stem from upgrading to Flash Player 10. The answers suggested already did not work for me and I'd lost hope in trying to fix it since finding an [open bug at Facebook](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12112) covering it. But [Henson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229424/henson) has posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256756/575530) that fixed it for me. In the JavaScript in my site master I removed the lines

```
    FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) {
       //HACK: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168
        FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b;
    };
```

and now it works. (N.B. I have not checked to see if the IE8 issue those lines were intended to overcome returns.)

========== EDIT ===========

I've just reread your question and since you are using ActionScript my answer is unlikely to be relevant. Although also JavaScript focussed the solutions suggested in [FB.login dialog does not close on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125254/575530) may prove useful. That question also lists some related StackOverflow questions and Facebook bugs.